# ¿Como retornar respuesta a funcion AJAX, formulario PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario con dos inputs, al dar clic en el botón, se ejecuta la funcion AJAX pero cuando se completa la funcion no sucede nada, no redirire a ninguna pagina, entonces quisier ayuda para identificar el problema, ojala puedan ayudarme
Codigo del formulario

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
      <label for="inputUser"> Username </label>
      <input type="text" id="inputUser" name ="inputUser">
      <label for="inpuPassword"> Password </label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name ="inputPassword">
      <input type="button" id="btnLoginForm" name="btnLoginForm" form="loginForm" value="Login">
    </form>
```

Codigo AJAX y JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var form = $("#btnLoginForm");
      $("#btnLoginForm").click(function(){
        var username = $('#inputUser').val();
        var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
        //Capturamos el formulario por su ID
        var form = $('#loginForm');

        $.ajax({
          type: form.attr('action'),
          url: form.attr('method'),
          data: form.serialize(),
          beforeSend:function(){
            $("#btnLoginForm").val('Sending...');
          },
          success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response == true){
              location.href ="indexUser.php";
            } else {
              location.href ="indexUser.php";
            }
          },
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Como vieron, tengo el IF de forma que sea false o true, de igual forma redireccione a la pagina, es una forma de comprobar si la variable response estaba llegando y si el método se ejecutaba bien hasta ahí
Codigo de php de "Login.php" (Destino del formulario):

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

if ($_POST) {
  $username = $_POST['inputUser'];
  $password = $_POST['inputPassword'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
  $result = $conexion->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $response = true;
    $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $user_id = $value['id'];
    //set session_start
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $user_id;
  }

  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error está aquí:

```
      type: form.attr('action'),
      url: form.attr('method'),
```

Ahí tienes los parámetros al revés de modo que como `url` estarías indicando el atributo `method` del formulario.

Debería ser así:

```
      url: form.attr('action'),
      method: form.attr('method'),
```

Conviene también modernizar un poco tu código, cambiando ciertas funciones y usos que ya son obsoletos.
 - He cambiado document.ready por `function`
 - He cambiado `type` por `method`
 - He cambiado `success` por `done`

Y he quitado cosas inncesarias. Por ejemplo, si usas `serialize` no necesitas capturar los valores aparte en variables.

```
/* 
 *Se recomienda function() en lugar de document.ready
 *ya que éste es obsoleto desde jQuery 3
 */
$(function() {
  $("#btnLoginForm").click(function() {
    var form = $('#loginForm');
    $.ajax({
        method: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
          $("#btnLoginForm").val('Sending...');
        }
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response == true) {
          //location.href ="indexUser.php";
        } else {
          //location.href ="indexUser.php";
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Lo Cambié como lo colocaste y ahora me aparece el siguiente error en consola: SyntaxError: expected property name, got '.', Ajax:38:10

Comment: Disculpa, ya pude solucionar el error de sintaxis, muchas gracias !, de verdad lo necesitaba